# How to create identical ZipFiles / Eggs for identical file contents

Tags: python, zip, setuptools, egg

How can I create Zip files using Python that will be exactly identical given their file *contents* is identical?

The Python `ZipFile` module (or probably even the underlying Zip library) will store file modification dates in the archive, which will lead to differences in the produced Zip files.

Ultimately, I want to create Python eggs using Setuptools (`python setup.py bdist_egg`) that produce identical `*.egg` files for unchanged packaged contents. Right now, whenever I recreate (in an automated build process) an Egg, the egg file will change each time (since setuptools recopies the package contents upon each invocation).

Setuptools [uses](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/622aacf2a37bb642c7ea204cb4ba8222e8e39461/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py?at=default#cl-545) the Python ZipFile module.

```
import os, time, hashlib
from zipfile import ZipFile

tn = 'test.txt'
zn0 = "z0.zip"
zn1 = "z1.zip"
zn2 = "z2.zip"

with open(tn, 'w') as t:
   t.write("hello")

z0 = ZipFile(zn0, 'w')
z1 = ZipFile(zn1, 'w')
z2 = ZipFile(zn2, 'w')

z0.write(tn)
z1.write(tn)

time.sleep(2)
os.system("touch %s" % tn)

z2.write(tn)

h = []
for i in xrange(3):
   m = hashlib.sha256()
   m.update(open('z%d.zip' % i, 'rb').read())
   h.append(m.hexdigest())

print h[0] == h[1]
print h[0] == h[2]
```

The code outputs `True`, `False` while I'd like to have `True`, `True`.